# How to find the frequency of a categorical text data in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table of tennis players. On Tableau I'm trying to plot number of players from each country. The table looks like below. I'm unable to use 'bin' as it seems to work for only numerical data. How do I go about this?

```
Pla_ID Country_ Code
200001 SUI
200002 IND
200003 USA
200004 ITA
200005 USA
200006 USA
200007 ITA
200008 SUI
200009 SUI
200010 SUI
200011 CRO
200012 RUS
200013 RUS
200014 FRA
```

Comment: What do you want to bin? Dragging `Country_ Code` to columns and `Number of Records` to rows will give you the number of players from each country. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to tableau, how do I get number of records?

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!